# I want my tablerow sensitive to OnSwipe-touch in Android, but it is too sensitive to onClick

Tags: android, touch-event

I want to make my tableRow listen to OnSwipe, and then show a delete-button. I have added a gesturedetector and it shows the button when I swipe. But since I also have a onClick-listener, the onclick always fires and makes the user leave the activity.

I have tried to disable the OnClick-listener, but that didn't make a difference. 
I also want the button to stay visible even after the swipe, as it is now is goes away after the swipe is finished.

```
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
    float velocityY) {
    try {
    if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
    return false;
    // right to left swipe
    tr.setEnabled(false);
    btnDelete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is actually a good question. I feel many of us would like to have a phone that is smart enough to have a 0 percent failure rate at detecting when we click or slide. (Maybe we should buy an iphone :) )

Changing the sensitivity of one app looks strange as a solution for a problem that is clearly linked to android and the hardware layer.

Comment: Please post full code. Onclick is missing, catch-block is missing....what are you returning, when swipe is recognized? Currently it seems like you're returning nothing...

Comment: I will use long click instead. It is easier to detect. Thanks anyway!